# Initialize msal instance using Azure MSAL Browser CDN js

Tags: azure, msal.js

I am trying to initialize an object to PublicClientApplication using Azure MSAL Browser js CDN. But I am getting Msal is undefined.

CDN: https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.5.2/js/msal-browser.min.js

I know we cannot use `import * as Msal  from "@azure/msal-browser"` from Javascript.

```
$.getScript("https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.5.2/js/msal-browser.min.js",function(){
   const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: "11111111-1111-1111-111111111111",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        knownAuthorities: [],
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:3001",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:3001/logout",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
     }
   const msalInstance = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to use?

Comment: $.getScript("https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.5.2/js/msal-browser.min.js",function(){
    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: "11111111-1111-1111-111111111111",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
            knownAuthorities: [],
            redirectUri: "https://localhost:3001",
            postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:3001/logout",
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
        }
    const msalInstance = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
})

Answer (score 2):

After adding the script reference in page (instead of Jquery getScript), it started working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.5.2/js/msal-browser.min.js"></script>
```